Extract from regexp_substr
Based on the below query , have to extract only the all "C"codes using regexp_substr. Anyone help on this?
select ('B211-C342,B211-C767,B211-C768,B211-C769,B211-C999')
from dual;

Expected result:
C342,C767,C768,C769,C999

What is your DBMS? Have you tried anything yourself already?

sql only. I have tried before but not got exact result

No, there is no "SQL only". You must use a database system where you use SQL to query the database's data. But DBMS differ, so the SQL dialect they feature differs. We must know your DBMS in order to know what syntax is available. Are you using MySQL maybe? Or SQL Server? Or Oracle? Or PostgreSQL? ... We must have this information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here are the additional info. Have extract only 'C' code based on the below data  'B211-C342,B211-C767,B211-C768,B211-C769,B211-C999'  Expected result: C342,C767,C768,C769,C999

Your source data is not rich. And the DBMS used is not specified.
I will offer the simplest solution for your example
with src as( 
  select 'B211-C342,B211-C767,B211-C768,B211-C769,B211-C999' tstr
)
select *
  ,replace(tstr,'B211-','') new_tstr
from src




tstr
new_tstr




B211-C342,B211-C767,B211-C768,B211-C769,B211-C999
C342,C767,C768,C769,C999



The solution may be more interesting if you describe the data variations.

Hi, thanks for your reply. My dbms is oracle SQL developer. If you provide the solution by using "regexp_substr" it would be helpful for me.
